# Image left side of text

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with getting images to show up on the left side of another div with text.

After a certain breakpoint I would like the image to hang on the left side of the text, I tried some things like float: left, tried playing around with the display: block etc but it wont budge at all.

My exact breakpoint is anywhere under 768px then the images have to stack left of the text, max width 150px.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQzZax

```css
#mu-featured {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#mu-featured h2 {
  font-family: lato;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#mu-featured p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #999;
}

.mu-featured-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.mu-featured-area {
  padding: 70px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mu-featured-container {
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .mu-featured-img {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="mu-featured">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mu-featured-container">
        <div class="mu-featured-img">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/92623/pexels-photo-92623.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="mu-featured-content">
          <h2>TITLE</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mu-featured-container">
        <div class="mu-featured-img">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/92623/pexels-photo-92623.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="mu-featured-content">
          <h2>TITLE</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mu-featured-container">
        <div class="mu-featured-img">
          <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/92623/pexels-photo-92623.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="mu-featured-content">
          <h2>TITLE</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="">Call to action!</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to solve it. One way is to nest another 2-column grid inside each `col-*-4`. The breakpoints and widths are up to you..

https://www.codeply.com/go/d8v0VbCaho

```
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 mu-featured-container">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-4 mu-featured-img pr-1">
                        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/92623/pexels-photo-92623.jpeg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-8 mu-featured-content">
                        <h2>TITLE</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

CSS for max 150px image...

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .mu-featured-img img {
        max-width: 150px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes this does work except when the screen goes from tablet size (where it shows image left) to mobile  size it still snaps back to full image with text underneath. Regardless of my column breakpoints?

Comment: My exact breakpoint is anywhere under 768px then the images have to stack left of the text, max width 150px.

Comment: So they're stacked vertically (image above text) on large screens, and you only want left side images at 768px or less?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant.

Comment: Ok, then you need to adjust the breakpoints accordingly.. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, been updating the breakpoints a little more and now it does exactly what I wanted!